# Get the first 32 bit (4 byte) number from NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdata

My NSString looks like this:

```
42949672951365185178
```

It is a concatenation of a 32 bit number `4294967295` and a timestamp `1365185178`.

I need to split the two so that I can get the number and the timestamp separately. All I know is that the first 32 bits is the "number" part and the rest is the timestamp.

This is what I have tried:

```
NSString *step9String = @"42949672951365185178";
NSData *step10uAndTS = [step9String dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSRange uidRange = NSMakeRange(0, 4); // 4 bytes
UInt8 uidBytes[uidRange.length];
[step10uAndTS getBytes:&uidBytes range:uidRange];

NSData *uidData = [NSData dataWithBytes:uidBytes length:sizeof(uidBytes)];
NSString *uid = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:uidData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// and the rest should be the timestamp
NSRange tsRange = NSMakeRange(4, step10uAndTS.length-4);
UInt8 tsBytes[tsRange.length];
[step10uAndTS getBytes:&tsBytes range:tsRange];

NSData *tsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:tsBytes length:sizeof(tsBytes)];
NSString *ts = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tsData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"UID: %@, TS: %@", uid, ts);
```

However I'm getting this output:

> UID: 4294, TS: 9672951365185466

Not sure what is going wrong here, or how to do it differently. If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong and how to remedy I'll be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense. How do you know where to split the string? You know it's 32 bit long, but unless it's zero-padded, its decimal representation makes the ambiguity arise.

Comment: You did not present enough information on how to determine which part of the string belongs to the number and which to the timestamp. After all `00` also is the concatenation of a 32bit number and a timestamp.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. The first bit will ALWAYS be padded to 32 bits. e.g. in the example the first number `4294967295` is equal to `0xFFFFFFFF` (32 bits) (You'll have to excuse my ignorance, this stuff isn't really my forté)

Comment: Dou you mean the most significant bit of the first number is always set (1)?

Comment: Can you give us another example? i.e. if the first bit was 55 would you have 551365185466 or would you have 00000000551365185466? The string  representation of a 32-bit number can be from 1 to 10 decimal digits long.

Comment: I see what you mean. it will be 00000000551365185466

Comment: Then the two parts are just `[step9String substringToIndex:10]` and `[step9String substringFromIndex:10]`.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. (I feel a bit silly now). I guess I hadn't thought about that. If its not padded like that, I guess that means there is no way to tell where to substring it? Because in @Ferruccio's example the first bit could be 55 or 551 or 5513 etc...?

Comment: @ThomasClayson The problem is that the decimal representation is not zero-padded, so you can't decide where the boundary between the two numbers lies.

Comment: Ok, then it has to be 0 padded. :) Thanks guys. Sorry to waste your time. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Not a waste of time IMO; kind of an interesting question actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Moving info from comments to answer.</sub>

There's no way to solve this problem without one of the two parts having a known string length, because the decimal representation of an integer that fits in 32 bits can have anywhere from 1 to 10 digits long. For example, the strings `01365185178` or `45981365185466` also fit your constraints as written -- a 32-bit number, `0` or `4598`, followed by a timestamp. How do we determine where the "first 4 bytes" ends, though? In the first case it's one character, in the second it's four.

If in fact you do know the length of one of them, then this is as simple as slicing the string. Since you've indicated that the UID portion must be zero-padded, that looks like this:

```
NSString * UID = [step9String substringToIndex:10];
NSString * timestamp = [step9String substringFromIndex:10];
```

What's going wrong for you is that the information in your string is made up of characters, each of which takes up one byte. When you put the information into an `NSData` object, it's still characters -- there's no automatic conversion to binary `int`. You would need an `NSScanner` object or `scanf()` or similar for that. Therefore, when you access the first four bytes of your data object, you're simply getting the first four characters of your original string.

Comment: Brilliant thanks for this concise answer which brings together all the info from the comments. :) I'll look into NSScanner and scanf() thanks for pointing me towards them.